# PHP MYSQL SELECT with multiple AND

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
Table "jeunes_subs"(id_jeune,id_subs).
```

How do i get the id_jeune with for example `id_subs =1 AND id_subs=2 AND id_subs=3`??
Its basic i know,but i'm looking for a basic query.

Comment: Yeah!!Thanks for replying,but it didn't work.The result is empty,even with the having count.

Comment: I want something like :
select id_jeune from jeunes_substantifs where (id_sub=1 and id_sub=2....)

Comment: This is what i did and worked in case somebody want to know:
SELECT distinct id_jeune FROM jeunes_subs WHERE id_subs IN (1,2,3) GROUP By id_jeune HAVING COUNT (*)=3